# Как мне использоваться переменную из одного метода в другом

Tags: javascript, ооп

Задание "Описать класс, представляющий треугольник. Предусмотреть методы для создания
объектов, вычисления площади, периметра и точки пересечения медиан. Описать
свойства для получения состояния объекта."
Как можно объявить переменную perimetr что бы можно было её использовать в методе получения периметра, а затем можно было взять значение этой переменной для вычисления к примеру площади треугольника.

```js
class Triangle{

 constructor(sideFirst, sideSecond, sideThird){
   this.sideFirst = sideFirst;
   this.sideSecond = sideSecond;
   this.sideThird = sideThird;
 }

 getPerimetrTriangle(){
 let perimetr = (0.5 * (this.sideFirst + this.sideSecond + this.sideThird));
  alert(perimetr);
 }
 getSquareTriangle(){

 }

}

let triangleOne = new Triangle(10,10,14);
triangleOne.getPerimetrTriangle();
```

Правильно ли с геттерами и сеттерами ?

```js
class Triangle{

 constructor(sideFirst, sideSecond, sideThird){
   this.sideFirst = sideFirst;
   this.sideSecond = sideSecond;
   this.sideThird = sideThird;
 }
 get sideFirst() {
    return this._sideFirst;
  }

 get sideSecond() {
    return this._sideSecond;
  }
 get sideThird() {
    return this._sideThird;
  }

 set sideFirst(value){
    if ( value <= 0) {
        alert('Этого не может быть');
        return;
    }
       this._sideFirst = value;
 }

  set sideSecond(value){
    if ( value <= 0) {
        alert('Этого не может быть');
        return;
    }
       this._sideSecond = value;
 }

  set sideThird(value){
    if ( value <= 0) {
        alert('Этого не может быть');
        return;
    }
       this._sideThird = value;
 }

}
```

Comment: Вопрос поставлен неправильно. Нужно не "как объявить", а вернуть ее из метода. Как это делается написано в каждом учебнике.

Comment: Вы про геттеры и сеттеры?

Comment: Допустим, про геттеры и сеттеры.

Comment: Правильно я оформил ?

Comment: Метод `getPerimetrTriangle` должен возвращать значение, т.е. `return perimetr`.